# Exchange Transport Rule to block combination of recipients?

Tags: exchange, exchangeonline, rules, smtp-headers

Is it possible to create an ETR that blocks certain combinations of recipients? Imagine I have two customers in different domains with similar email addresses. I want to prevent sending to recipient lists that inadvertently mix users from the two domains.

Ideally, I'd block outbound messages with `*@domainA.com AND *@domainB.com` recipients. Also, blocking outbound messages with `user@domainA.com AND *@domainB.com` would be acceptable.

Consider also that the recipients list might be:

```
TO: user@domainA.com
CC: user@domainB.com
```

Exchange rule predicates seem to be "any" operators. Further, it seems I can't use the same condition twice; it's greyed out on the second condition.

[image: Screnshot of Exchange Transport rule criteria]

Answer (score 0):

Is Exchange 2019 or Exchange Online?You could use “ address matches any of these words”, it can be added multiple domains:

[image]

Comment: Exchange Online. Wouldn't your proposed rule block emails with only a single recipient in either domain?

Answer (score 0):

In Exchange Online, you also could add two domains into the “domain is”:
[image]

To block outbound messages with user@domainA.com AND *@domainB.com, you could refer to the following settings:

[image]